# Running Chrome appears as Plex

Tags: launcher, google-chrome

When I run Google Chrome (even when typing 'google-chrome' in the command line) I get chrome to open but it appears on the launcher as a Plex window. This has just happened today, and I think it's because I ran Plex after restarting without running chrome alone first. Restarting fixes it, but why is this association made in the taskbar from chrome to Plex?

[The Blue X is the Plex icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqDN8.png)

Comment: Sorry for the OT and sorry for not being able to help you, but what is your icon theme? I like it! :D

Comment: @dadexix86 - Numix circle icon